# Multilevel Dynamic Menu in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create multilevel menu in ASP.NET MVC. I need a suggestion what the best practice for creating this will be, so that I can use the menu on every page.

Should I create a partial view or is there any other best way?

Thank you

Comment: add that in your layout/master page .. and it will be in your every page ..

Comment: should design your menu as hierarchy, can refer https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1077799/Creating-Dynamics-Tree-View-Menu-in-ASP-NET-MVC-in

Comment: I know but when I am creating dynamic menu in Layout/master I always need pass menu parameter for each Controller, is there any way to create global variable that will load automatically when every and each page execute.

Answer (score 0):

In your `views` folder => `shared` => `_Layout.cshtml`

This `_Layout.cshtml` will be your template of all your pages to be made.

If you create a new Page, in .cshtml you will see

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

This means your new page has a master page or template page name `_Layout.cshtml`. Your menu must be here.

Comment: I got that, for dynamic menu where I should place my database connection and data fetching from sql server. that will automatically load when every and each page execute.

Comment: if you are using `EF`, most of connection string is in the web.config file. this https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/introduction.aspx can help you.